# How to execute a function to every item in a range

Tags: python, list, function

I got a list of functions after calling the function `count()` below. I want to know how to execute these functions besides using the way in my code.

```
def count():
    fs = []
    for i in range(1, 4):
        def f():
             return i*i
        fs.append(f)
    return fs

print(count()[0](), count()[1](), count()[2]())
```

Comment: `for f in count(): print(f())`?

Comment: Even if we follow correction by  'jonrsharpe'. The resulting execution will take reference of 'i' and will render value on your call which will always be 3 in your case. hence answer for all calls will be 9. I believe you don't want this. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to apply a function to every item in an iterable. The result, in Python 3.x, is an iterable.

There are several different ways you can then extract results. Below is an example.

I have also corrected some errors in your logic. Your function `f` should take a parameter, presumably `i`, as this is used in your function. Similarly, it seems you want the function `count` to take a parameter `n` to determine your range of inputs.

```
def count(n):
    def f(i):
        return i*i
    return map(f, range(1, n))

## iterate using next
res = count(5)

print(next(res))  # 1
print(next(res))  # 4
print(next(res))  # 9

## iterate using for loop
for k in count(4):
    print(k)
# 1
# 4
# 9

## build list and exhaust all results
print(list(count(4)))
# [1, 4, 9]
```